# Why was the kanji 安 chosen for "cheap"?

Tags: kanji

I have studied Chinese for over 20 years and am now learning Japanese.

When learning Chinese characters at the start there are a number of kind of funny examples that are usually shown to give an idea of how Chinese characters are put together.

One of these is 安 which means "peace" in Chinese. The character shows a woman under a roof. The explanation humorously given is that a woman with a house/home is a happy woman, or something along those lines.

I was surprised to discover recently that 安 is "cheap/やすい" in Japanese.

Why was this character chosen as the kanji for "cheap" ?

Comment: FYI: https://www.waraerujd.com/安い

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you look at the dictionary meaning of 安 in Japanese, you can see that while it does mean cheap (安い/やすい) it can also mean peaceful. I'd also like to note that many Japanese words have two readings, a *kun-yomi* reading and an *on-yomi* reading. *Kun* readings are generally used in Japanese words for their reading alone, while *on* readings are used for borrowed Chinese meanings or words. 安 has a *kun* reading of やす and an *on* reading of あん.
You can see in some words that it retains its original meaning and reading: 安心 (あんしん) can mean relief, or peace of mind. 安定 (あんてい) can mean stability, and composure.
However, *it seems that some Japanese words relating to peacefulness were read as "やす,"* in particular 安らか (peaceful) and 休まる (feel at ease). Here, 安 was chosen for its meaning, but its reading was ignored to accommodate the original Japanese reading

**Judging from this**, it is likely that since 安 was used in words where it was read as やす, it became generally associated with that reading. Therefore, when people sought to write "cheap," which was already read as "やすい," with kanji, they chose 安 based on its *kun* reading with little regard to the *on* reading or original meaning.

Comment: Wouldn't it be an example of ateji then?

Comment: Yes, I believe it would count as ateji @homocomputeris